# Python's regex module: repeating 'backreferences' does not appear to work correctly

Tags: python, regex

**Note: I am using the PyPi alternative regex module**

I have a python program in which I am looking for repeated labels in a specific format, separated by commas.

The format is: (*words...* #*number*)

For example: `Trial #1, Trial #2, Run #3,` and `Spring trial #13` would all fit in the format.

I am using: `([\w ]*#\d\d?,)\1*` in a raw string as my regex pattern.

In java, and in various regex testing engines, using `findall()` with this pattern on the string:

> Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3, (...
>
> ...) Run #20,Run #20,Run #20,Run #20,Run #20,Run #20,Run #20

returns:

> match 1: **Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,**
>
> match 2: **Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,**
>
> ...etc.

but in python, it returns:

> match 1: **Run #1,**
>
> match 2: **Run #2,**
>
> ...etc.

I want it to return the first result (the one returned by java's and other program's regexes)

Is there something I'm ignoring about python's regex engine? Why am I getting this result?

my code is:

```
import regex

file = open('Pendulum Data.csv',mode='r')
header1 = file.readline()
header2 = file.readline()

pattern1 = regex.compile(r'([\w ]*#\d\d?)\1*',flags=regex.V0)
header1Match = pattern1.findall(header1)
for x in header1Match:
    print(x)
```

The for loop and print statement are for viewing the results.

(which brings me to another question: what exactly does `regex.findall()` return? Is `findall()` returning what I want while I am just printing my results wrong?)

...and yes, I am using a raw string for my pattern.

Comment: Use `re.finditer` rather than `re.findall` as it will keep all the groups. `header1Match = pattern1.finditer(header1)
for x in header1Match:
    print(x.group(0))`. And I guess you are using [`([\w ]*#\d\d?,)\1*` regex](https://regex101.com/r/tM1rR2/2).

Comment: The regex in the code sample is different from the one at the top of your question. For example, it will not match if there is a space after the commas separating the matches, unless there was a space at the start of the first match...

Comment: No need to use the regex module instead of the re module if you use the flag `flags=regex.V0` that is supposed to mimic the re module behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now :). I will read up on the "finditer" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a capturing group in your regex. Python `.finall` returns the tuples of captured texts if capturing groups are specified in the pattern. Thus, you are looking for a `.finditer` function.

See [Python `re.finditer` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

> Return an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) yielding [**MatchObject**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE *pattern* in *string*. The *string* is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

and [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of *pattern* in *string*, as a list of strings. The *string* is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.**

Here is a [small demo](http://ideone.com/Kf0J5C) using `re.finditer`:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([\w ]*#\d\d?,)\1*')
test_str = "Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3, (..."
print [x.group() for x in p.finditer(test_str)]
```

Result:

```
['Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,Run #1,', 'Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,Run #2,', 'Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,Run #3,']
```

Casimir is right, with such a trivial regular epxression, you can use the regular `re` module.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!